# Loop through line for multiple values

Tags: powershell

Word Doc content: [(7)]/[(8)]   [ Security Agent 1] as security trustee for the Secured Parties (the "Security Agent") ; and

Value to extract is "Security Agent 1"

It extracts 7 as thats the first within bracket.

Below code works fine, but will give only first occurence/value within brackets. Need to loop it through multiple values within bracket and give me the 3rd value in bracket

```
$FinalTable = Get-Content $SourceFile|
        select-string -pattern $SearchKeyword |
        Select -Property @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Line}}, @{Name = 'LineNo'; Expression = {$_.LineNumber}}, @{Name='Criteria';Expression = {$_.Category}} |
        ForEach-Object {

        $str = $_.Name
        $LineNumber = $_.LineNo
        $Criteria = $_.Criteria
        $start = $str.indexOf("[") + 1
        $end = $str.indexOf("]", $start)
        $length = $end - $start
        $result = ($str.substring($start, $length)).trim()

        #Creating a custom object to display in table format
        $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Category -Value $Category
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $result

        $obj
    } 
 $FinalTable | Export-Csv -Path $DestinationFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Trying this as theo suggested but didn't worked

```
$FinalTable = Get-Content $SourceFile|
        select-string -pattern $SearchKeyword |
        Select -Property @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$_.Line}}, @{Name = 'LineNo'; Expression = {$_.LineNumber}}, @{Name='Criteria';Expression = {$_.Category}} |
        ForEach-Object {

        $str = $_.Name
        $LineNumber = $_.LineNo
        $Criteria = $_.Criteria

        #$start = $str.indexOf("[") + 1
        #$end = $str.indexOf("]", $start)
        #$length = $end - $start
        #$result = ($str.substring($start, $length)).trim()
                #Write-host $str
        if ($str -match '(\[[^\]]+])\/(\[[^\]]+])\s*\[\s*([^\]]+)]') {
            # $matches[1] --> "(7)"
            # $matches[2] --> "(8)"
            $result = $matches[3]  # --> "Security Agent 1"
            } 
        Write-Host $result
        #Creating a custom object to display in table format
        $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Category -Value $Category
        Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $result

        $obj
    } 
 $FinalTable | Export-Csv -Path $DestinationFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Sorry, I've read the first 5 lines of your question, but I don't understand, what you are saying.

Comment: Edited the regex in my answer, because the first one included the square brackets for `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`. I know you don't want these matches, but now it is better I think.

Comment: Probably this _didn't work_ because you made two mistakes elsewhere in your code. 1) you should use `Select-String -pattern ([regex]::Escape(($SearchKeyword))` because if your `$SearchKeyword` contains characters like `\[(` the result will be not what you expect. 2) You are storing the `$_.Category` value under the variablename `$Criteria`. Later you add the _undefined_ variable `$Category` to the $Obj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regular Expression to get the parts between the brackets in a string like `[(7)]/[(8)] [ Security Agent 1] as security trustee for the Secured Parties (the "Security Agent")`.

Instead of

```
$start = $str.indexOf("[") + 1
$end = $str.indexOf("]", $start)
$length = $end - $start
$result = ($str.substring($start, $length)).trim()
```

do

```
if ($str -match '\[([^\]]+)\]\/\[([^\]]+)\]\s*\[\s*([^\]]+)]') {
    # $matches[1] --> "(7)"
    # $matches[2] --> "(8)"
    $result = $matches[3]  # --> "Security Agent 1"
} 
else {
    $result = ''   # should not happen..
}
```

Comment: didnt worked for me , gave me nothing in result output. I have updated code in question i'm trying now

Comment: @user3657339 This is an accurate answer for what you described.

Comment: $x.split('[')[2].split(']')[0].trim()... this worked